# How to fix #2014 - Commands out of sync; on running stored procedure from the console

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to join 3 tables together in MySQL with an stored procedure and union them.

I have already checked all code and parameters on syntax error or wrong names but i can't find them.

Stored Procedure: GetOpenOrderFromUser()

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`present`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetOpenOrderFromUser`(IN `UserIDParam` INT)
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE OrderIDParam INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT OrderID INTO OrderIDParam FROM _newapp_shop_orders WHERE UserID = UserIDParam AND Status = 'Open';

SELECT 'events' as Type,
                Id,
                Foto,
                Video,
                Titel,
                Omschrijving,
                Datum_Begin,
                Datum_Eind,
                Win,
                Bovenaan,
                Lat,
                Lng,
                _newapp_shop_order_items.OrderID,
                _newapp_shop_order_items.Amount,
                _newapp_shop_products_events.CategoryID,
                _newapp_shop_products_events.Price,
                _newapp_shop_products_events.DiscountPercent
 FROM ((Events
  INNER JOIN _newapp_shop_products_events ON Events.Id = _newapp_shop_products_events.EventID)
   INNER JOIN _newapp_shop_order_items ON Events.Id = _newapp_shop_order_items.EventID)
    WHERE _newapp_shop_order_items.OrderID = OrderIDParam
    UNION ALL
SELECT 'activities' as Type,
                Id,
                Foto,
                Video,
                Naam as 'Titel',
                Omschrijving,
                Datum_begin,
                Datum_eind,
                Win,
                Bovenaan,
                Lat,
                Lng,
                _newapp_shop_order_items.OrderID,
                _newapp_shop_order_items.Amount,
                _newapp_shop_products_activitys.CategoryID,
                _newapp_shop_products_activitys.Price,
                _newapp_shop_products_activitys.DiscountPercent
 FROM ((Activiteiten
  INNER JOIN _newapp_shop_products_activitys ON Activiteiten.Id = _newapp_shop_products_activitys.ActivityID) 
   INNER JOIN _newapp_shop_order_items ON Activiteiten.Id = _newapp_shop_order_items.ActivityID)
    WHERE _newapp_shop_order_items.OrderID = OrderIDParam;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The stored procedure works sometimes, when I run it from phpmyadmin it works but from code and the mysql terminal it gives this error:

```
Expression missing. (near "ON" at position 25)

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now.
```

Comment: If it does not work from code, please add the code. The usual reason for this problem is that you did not fetch all results (and how to do this will depend on your code/language). The MySQL client (if that is what you mean by "mysql terminal") should do this correctly though, so you may need to clarify this part. Also, "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;" is not part of your query, it seems to be inserted by your code/phpmyadmin (although usually not by the mysql client either), so you need to be more precise in that regard too.

Comment: @Solarflare Yes i meant the console in phpmyadmin at the bottom. I've already corrected the fetching in the php so that is not the issue. I use CALL GetOpenOrderFromUser(12); at the console.

Comment: If you corrected the fetching in your code and you still get the error, you didn't fix it completely. So the request remains: please add the relevant client code. To elaborate: that error is *exclusive* to something a client (e.g. your php code) does. It cannot happen by a stored procedure alone, so your sql code is not enough to answer your question.